# indexOf not returning correct index

Tags: javascript, indexof

Re: Hangman Game

Objective: after user guess a letter, retrieve the index of the letter in the word.

Issue: The number returned is not the correct index of the word. It's the 3rd to the last line of code.

I'm a newbie so go easy on me please :)  This is so hard!

```
// JavaScript Document


$(document).ready(function() {      // upon page load

    var badGuesses;   // reset bad guess counter
    var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Z"];   // array of letters to choose
    $("#lettersRemaining").html(alphabet);  // gets elements of the alphabet array and displays on UI

//  N E W  G A M E  B U T T O N   C L I C K E D

$("#newGame").click(function() {    // when user clicks on Start New Game button...

    $("#status").hide();   // upon game reset hide the status section stating game over
    badGuesses = 0;   // reset guess counter which is used later
    var wordCollection = ["mansion", "statue", "gorilla", "notebook", "smartphone", "illustration", "photo", "elegant", "arborist", "keyboard", "calendar", "capital", "textbook", "horrible", "library"];  //  array of words
    var theWord = wordCollection[Math.floor(Math.random()*wordCollection.length)]; // randomly selects a word 
        console.log("theWord is ....");
        console.log(theWord);

    var theWordLength = theWord.length;     // Get number of characters in randomly selected word 
        console.log("theWordLength is ....");
        console.log(theWordLength);

// D I S P L A Y  D A S H E S

    var combineDashes = []; // creates an array to hold the number of dashes inside the for loop
    for (var i = theWordLength; i > 0; i--) 
        {
            combineDashes.push(" - ");  // each loop through adds a dash to the array
        }
    combineDashes.join(" ");  // joins cumulative dashes and converts to a string
    $("#dashes").html(combineDashes); // displays dashes on UI

});


// G U E S S   L E T T E R

$("#guessLetter").click(function(theWord) {     // when user clicks on the Guess Letter button pass in theWord value ....
    var letter = $("#theLetter").val();   // gets the letter the user is guessing
    console.log("letter is ...");
    console.log(letter);

    // Is the letter a good or bad guess?
    var letterContained = theWord.toString().indexOf(letter);  // <-- NOT WORKING!! returns index from theWord for the letter guessed; -1 means bad guess
    console.log("letterContained is...");
    console.log(letterContained);


});

});
```

Comment: Have you tried theWord.indexOf without the toString()

Comment: I think your alphabet is upper case and your words are lower case and indexOf is case sensitive.

Comment: If my hunch is right, setting theWord=wordCollection[your selecting here].toUpperCase() should help

Comment: @JeremyKahan I did try without the toString() and it didn't work so I researched and found a previous post where the fix was to add toString() so I tried it.   I also changed the words array so they are all capitalized -and-   used capital letter for the guess.  I updated post accordingly and provided console response as well. Thank you !

Comment: @JeremyKahan regarding your hunch, I changed the array to all caps so I think I'm good there.

Comment: My hunch could not have been the only issue then, what happens if you put console.log("theWord is ....");
        console.log(theWord); inside your guessLetter function like before the var letterContained line. Does theWord hold the value you think?

Comment: Because it looks like theWord is local to newGame.click() and so would not be passable by guessLetter.click(). If that hunch is right, moving the declaration of var theWord up to where you declare badGuesses and just setting theWord= later (no var) could work.

Comment: The console returns -->   r.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: input#guessLetter, currentTarget: input#guessLetter, relatedTarget: null…}
 When I expand the error  oh man.. it goes on forever. Not sure you want me to paste it in here...

Comment: I tried moving variable declaration up by badGuesses. Console still returning previously mentioned error -->r.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: input#guessLetter, currentTarget: input#guessLetter, relatedTarget: null…}
script.js:52 letterContained is...

Comment: So theWord as a parameter to .click is the click event object or some such nonsense. Just calling it "theWord" does not make it what you want it to be. Get rid of the parameter theWord and instead declare theWord where I suggested.

Comment: ultimately still getting "-1" as the value of letterContained

Comment: That did it !!  I removed theWord as the parameter and it works!  Thanks so much for putting up with my ignorance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all in the comments above, but the problem was that theWord needed to be declared at the same level as badGuesses (and assigned but not declared in newGame, just like badGuesses) and be removed as a parameter to guessLetter. Then guessLetter had the desired value of theWord, and the indexOf call worked.